# Immutable.js Combine with React Typescript

Tags: typescript, immutable.js, react-typescript

I'm having a hard time refactor my reducers to TS since I'm using Immutable.js in my project
This is my reducer:

```
export interface DashboardState {
   componentId: number | null;
   dashboard: number | null;
}

let defaultState: DashboardState = {
   componentId: null,
   dashboard: null,
};

export default function (state = Map<string, number>(defaultState), action):  
Map<string, number> {
    switch (action.type) {
        case dashboardsActionsTypes.SET_PROJECT_VIEW:
            return state.set('componentId', action.payload);
        case dashboardsActionsTypes.SET_DASHBOARD_TYPE:
            return state.set('dashboard', action.payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the Map(defaultState) that says:
[image]

What I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: `Map` is a ... map with getter and setters etc, regardless of what data you store in it. I guess your state would have to be `defaultState : Immutable.Map<string, any>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to construct a `Map`.

```
export function Map<K, V>(collection: Iterable<[K, V]>): Map<K, V>;
export function Map<V>(obj: {[key: string]: V}): Map<string, V>;
export function Map<K, V>(): Map<K, V>;
export function Map(): Map<any, any>;
```

The error on the first overload is expected because you definitely shouldn't match that one.  Your object is closer to the second overload, but you don't match that overload automatically because it involves a `string` index signature which `DashboardState` does not have.

The quick and dirty solution here involves setting a generic on the `Map` function.  As you can see, the second overload is the only one with just `<V>` instead of `<K, V>`.  So you can match this overload by setting just a value type for the `Map`.  In this case the value type of `DashboardState` is `any`.

```
state = Map<any>(defaultState)
```

---

The type support with this setup is extremely weak. The keys of `state` can be any `string` and the values can be absolutely anything.  Why bother using Typescript at all if you can't get any useful information out of it?

I recommend using the official [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) which has strong typescript support as well as support for immutability using [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/).  And replace the `any` in your `DashboardState` with the actual types.

---

**Edit:**

After viewing your edit, I recommend that you use optional properties (`number | undefined`) instead of `number | null` since `Map.get()` includes `undefined` along with the expected value.  So you would get `number | null | undefined`.  If using optional properties then you don't actually need an initial state at all.  You can use an empty `Map`.

We can also limit the keys to just the keys of `DashboardState`.

Use these utilities on any state type:

```
export type MapOf<T> = Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]>;

const createMap = <T,>(): MapOf<T> => Map<keyof T, T[keyof T]>();
```

For the dashboard:

```
export interface DashboardState {
  componentId?: number;
  dashboard?: number;
}

export default function (state = createMap<DashboardState>(), action): MapOf<DashboardState> {
   switch (action.type) {
       case dashboardsActionsTypes.SET_PROJECT_VIEW:
           return state.set('componentId', action.payload);
       case dashboardsActionsTypes.SET_DASHBOARD_TYPE:
           return state.set('dashboard', action.payload);
       default:
           return state;
   }
}
```

Comment: Paist Thanks for the explanations. I updated my code and added types to the default state and typed the Map constructor. I'm not sure I understand how to solve the issue since I'm still getting the same error. Can you write any example so maybe I will understand it better?

Comment: `export default function (state = Map<number | null>(defaultState), action):  
Map<string, number | null>` and remove the type from `defaultState`.  But you should use `undefined` instead of `null` since `Map.get()` includes `undefined`.  And really you should just use Redux Toolkit :)